# Como mostrar solo una parte de un dato desde AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el cual esta conectada a una base de datos que depende de la fecha que uno escriba te da un valor. Si entro a Network me muestra todo el valor correctamente con su fecha pero lo que yo quiero es poder imprimir una parte de ese valor en un span (con id="practicando"). 
Espero que me puedan ayudar, les agradeceria infinitamente! Muchas gracias!

```
<div id='formulario'>

            <label for='FechaReg' >Fecha de regulacion:</label>
            <input type='date' id='FechaReg' name='CJFECH' class='unorequerido' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' min='1948-01-01' max='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?> required> 

<select id='valor_jus' name='valor_jus'>
            <option id='opcion'></option>
            </select></div>
```

Luego esta esta es la parte de javascript:

```
 $("#FechaReg").change(function(){
    const FechaReg = $("#FechaReg");
        //CARGAMOS EL JUS
        $.ajax({
        url : "/form/carga-jus.php",
        type : "POST",
        data: { valor_select2:FechaReg.val() //En que dato lo buscamos (prueba.ajax2.php)      
        },
        dataType : "JSON",
        success : function(recibido) {  
        for(var i = 0; i<recibido['DATA'].length; i++){
            document.getElementById("valor_jus").options[i]=new Option(recibido['DATA'][i]['VALOR_JUS']);
        }
        }
        });

});
```

Este es el carga-jus.php

```
   <?php 


include('conexion.php');
 $dato_desde_ajax = $_POST['valor_select1']; //Lo ingresamos en el DATA del ajax en change
//$dato_desde_ajax = '01/06/2019';
var_dump($dato_desde_ajax);
$dato_desde_ajax = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dato_desde_ajax));
var_dump($dato_desde_ajax);
$data=array();

$sql="SELECT OBTENER_JUS_FECHA('$dato_desde_ajax') AS VALOR_JUS
        FROM DUAL"; 



$stid = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);


while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {    

    array_push($data, array('VALOR_JUS'=>$row['VALOR_JUS'])); 
    // array_push($data, array('GRUPO'=>$row['GRUPO']));  
}

oci_close($connection);

$json_data=array();
$json_data['DATA']=$data;

echo (json_encode($json_data));
?>
```

[image: Lo que yo quiero es mostrar 1875,53 en el span]

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu `carga-jus.php`?

Comment: Ahi mande la foto del carga-jus.php

Comment: Cambia la imagen por el texto del código, es complicado analizar el código en una imagen. Gracias.

Comment: Por otra parte, tienes que tener un `select` en el HTML al cual le agregues los `option` que recuperarías en el  `success`

Comment: Ahi cambie la imagen por codigo y cambie con un select al span

Comment: Asumiendo que los datos están llegando bien, lo cual no nos dices (deberías probarlo con un `console.log`), estás usando mal `new Option`, el cual requiere al menos dos parámetros separados por coma: `new Option(texto,valor)`. No veo que uses la coma. Por otra parte, deberías optimizar el código. Para tu caso, yo crearía una referencia al `select` fuera del bucle, crearía los `option` como cadena y luego, fuera del bucle, los agregaría al `select`. Como lo tienes ahora, el elemento se modifica `N` veces, tantas como elementos haya en el bucle, lo cual es poco performante.

Comment: Esto es totalmente confuso: `new Option(recibido['DATA'][i]['VALOR_JUS'])` si muestras en la pregunta lo que hay en `recibido` mediante un `console.log(recibido);` y nos dices que `value` y qué `texto` requieres para cada `option`, entonces podría ponerte un ejemplo, pero lo que estás pasando a `new Option()` no se entiende en absoluto por lo que no puedo aportarte una respuesta.

Comment: Básicamente tienes que hacer un .split() sobre el dato que quieras partir. Investiga sobre esta sentencia. Y si quieres más ayuda, por favor te lo pido, explicate mejor en tu pregunta diciendonos que quieres exactamente que haga la aplicación, con los datos que quieres que te muestre.